# How to implement a personalized search feature using Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, personalization

I need to implement a personalized search feature using Elasticsearch. My plan is to use Elasticsearch to perform a full-text search based on user queries, and then use **something else** to re-rank/re-score/personalize/etc the search results based on user data (past searches, company roles, known preferences, etc). I'm new to Elasticsearch.

My question is:

1. Is separating the full-text search and personalization layers a good solution? Or is there something that Elasticsearch provides that can do this already without using an additional "personalization" layer to perform on the search results from Elasticsearch?
2. What is that **something else** I can use?

Thank you for your help.